# In Apache NiFi, Is it possible to increase / decrease the scope of a controller?

Tags: apache-nifi

In Apache NiFi, I created a controller within the appropriate scope at that time. Now I want to use the same controller in other places. My question is can I change the scope to the current processors group's ancestor so it can be used by other  processors group ?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing the scope of existing `Controller services` is not yet possible in NiFi.

***Method-1:***

Define a **`controller service`** on **`root canvas level`** then this controller will be available on all Processor groups, Processors in NiFi instance with **`Scope`** as **`NiFi Flow`**.

***Method-2:***

Keep all the processor groups that are going to share same controller service in **`One Parent Processor group`** and define controller service on **`Parent Processor group`** then the defined controller service will be available to all the **`processor groups,Processors`** inside the parent processor group.

***Other way:***

Defining controller service on **`all the required processor groups`**.

Answer (score 7):

There's no current method to do this except the obvious way of recreating it although it would be a nice and convenient feature.

You could suggest it for the next version of NiFi